# How to print even index values of any array | NumPy |

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am a learner , bit stuck not getting how do i print the even indexed value of an array

**My code :**

```
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.array([2,4,6,11])
arr_1 [ (arr_1[ i for i in range(arr_1.size) ] ) % 2 == 0  ]
```

**Expected Output :**

```
2,6
```

2 -> comes under index 0

6 -> comes under index 2

Both are even index

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, You can use `[start:end:step]` from `list` and get what you want like below:

```
>>> arr_1 = np.array([2,4,6,11])
>>> arr_1[::2]
array([2, 6])

>>> list(arr_1[::2])
[2, 6]

>>> print(*arr_1[::2], sep=',')
2,6
```

Comment: I would say this is the correct way to do it, rather than loops or list comprehensions - it is much faster, it is the 'native' numpy way to do it, it's much cleaner code and so much less likely to have bugs etc etc

Answer (score 2):

- Your problem was that you were iterating through what `range()` function returned.
- which obviously wasn't your original `arr_1`
- in my code we just iterate through the `arr_1` without using any `range` or `length`

Code that will work:

```
import numpy as np

arr_1 = np.array([2,4,6,11])
arr_1 = [i for index, i in enumerate(arr_1) if ((index % 2) == 0)]

print(arr_1)
```

Output:

```
[2, 6]
```